# Google Maps low-res and blurry in PhoneGap 2.5

Tags: google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3

I'm developing a PhoneGap app that uses the Google Maps API. I've created high-res versions of a number of my graphics for display on higher resolution screens, which look very nice, but the map tiles themselves are very low-resolution and blurry. The map tiles on our mobile website, which is built from essentially the same code, are much sharper and better looking. (See [here](http://i138.photobucket.com/albums/q266/phenry1970/stackexchange/QNscreenshots_zpsfa5d92c0.png) for a full-sized comparison.)

My viewport tag is:

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" 
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

How can I make the map tiles look better in my app?

[image: Comparison of PhoneGap app and mobile website]

Comment: After seven years I'm having the same issue. Ionic app which uses Capacitor and a web view to render google maps. The image quality is terrible, especially the satellite layer. Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Been struggling with the same issue for age and it seems to be a DPI scaling issue in the WebView component used by Phonegap when having hardware acceleration enabled, which is turned on by default since Android 4.0.

You can force the hardware acceleration to be disabled by adding android:hardwareAccelerated="false" to the  tag in your AndroidManifest.xml and the map will be sharp again, but the rest of yoru app might be more sluggish, especially if you have heavy HTML/CSS elements.

Another solution is to set  in the  of your index.html to make the viewport use the native screen DPI, but then all your app will look tiny.

So unfortunately I haven't found any satisfactory solution yet, and there's not much more information about the issue around the web.