# google maps v3 blurry with cordova/phonegap

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3, cordova

I'm developing a jQuery mobile app with PhoneGap 3.3 (Cordova). My problem is, that Google Mmap looks very blurry. I found an [old stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578329/google-maps-low-res-and-blurry-in-phonegap-2-5) with the same problem.

The user posts this image:
[image]

Is there meanwhile a solution?

Comment: Have you faced this problem on different platforms?

Comment: No, because I'm developing an android app. I've tested it on android and my browser (Chrome), but only android has that problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you like to use my plugin **phonegap-googlemaps-plugin**?
https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin

You can run Google Maps SDKs on Android and iOS, and control it from JavaScript easily.

---

**Update:** Phonegap-GoogleMaps-Plugin v1.0.7 allows you to embed a map into your design.

See the example:

https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin/tree/master/example/v1.0.7-example

[image]